# Replace whitespaces with %20 to load images

Tags: c#, regex, razor

I am trying to use a image path as a div background but it does not show up since I am getting the property as

images/Listings/28023_Dorothy's Chuck Wagon.jpg

There are whitespaces and it should be the same url with the %20 instead the whitespaces to load the image.
Is there a way I can resolve that?

images/Listings/28023_Dorothy's%20Chuck%20Wagon.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Replace`?

```
String fixed_path = org_path.Replace(" ", "%20");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class to format file or web paths:

```
string path = @"http://www.somesite.com/some image file.png";
Uri uri = new Uri(path);
string corrected = uri.AbsoluteUri;

// corrected contains: http://www.somesite.com/some%20image%20file.png
```